# jQuery find and replace second one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I would go about finding and replacing some text in a div, but i want to find and replace the second occurrence of that text. For example:"You just added a item, please remove this item" so I would like to find the second "item" and replace it with whatever text I choose.

**JS:**

```
var compareCount = $('.compareWidget').find('.compareItem').length;

if (compareCount >= 2) {
    $('.message').find('.count').text(compareCount);
    $('message').html().replace('item', 'items');
}

$('.message').slideDown("Fast");

setTimeout(function () {
    $('.message').slideUp("Fast");
}, 5000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="alertMessage">
    <div class="message">
        <span>You just added a item to compare, you currently have <span class="count">1</span> item to compare</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you'd probably want to use a regular expression and get the second match.

Comment: Is it going to be a dynamic string or always "item"?

Comment: it always going to be "item" for this example

Comment: Best answer ever.  Seriously @Lawrence, will it always be `item` for EVERY example?  AKA every possible input when you apply this in the real world

Comment: can you show us some code...?

Comment: I just made a edit to show the code

Answer (score 2):

"you currently have 1 item to compare"
You want to turn item to items?

You can do it with regular expressions, or you can wrap it into an element and grab that.

```
<span class="count">1</span> <span class="type">item</span> to compare</span>
```

and

```
 $('.message').find('.type').text("items");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions you can

```
function replaceMatch(originalString, searchFor , replaceWith, matchNumber)
{
  var match = 0;
  return originalString.replace(searchFor, function(found){
                     match++;
                     return (match===matchNumber)?replaceWith:found;
                   },'g');
}
```

and call it like

```
var msg = $('.message');
msg.html( replaceMatch( msg.html(), 'item', 'items', 2) );
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/crhvA/