# replace the [x] match using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string:

```
"josh marie anne josh anne marie chloe josh anne ..."
```

If I found josh, I want to replace for JJJ. So I have a string replace like this:

```
var p = 'josh';
var username = 'JJJ';

$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(p, username));
```

the problem is, I don't want to replace the first `josh` in the string... I want to choose with one to replace (the second josh in the `#comment` or the first josh, of the third...)

Any ideas how to choose with one to replace?

html

```
<textarea id=comment>josh marie anne josh anne marie chloe josh anne josh marie anne josh anne marie chloe josh anne</textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tbjswpLb/

Comment: @rory OP don't want to replace all the occurrences. But the occurrence that he want. Suppose if it matches 7 words, he has to select any one occurrence from that and replace.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thank you friend!

Comment: see this [jquery-find-and-replace-second-one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388620/jquery-find-and-replace-second-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your logic like this to achive what you want,

```
var p = 'josh',username = 'JJJ',cnt = 0,replaceAt = 3;
var regEx = new RegExp(p,"g")

$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(regEx,function(matchedString){
  return (++cnt == replaceAt) ? username : matchedString;
}));
```

Use the `callBack` function of `replace` to match the occurrence series.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tbjswpLb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer From: [jquery-find-and-replace-second-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388620/jquery-find-and-replace-second-one)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/tbjswpLb/3/)

**Updated Scripts:**

```
var p = 'josh';
var username = 'JJJ';

var out = replaceMatch( $("#comment").val(), p, username, 2)

$("#comment").val(out);

function replaceMatch(originalString, searchFor , replaceWith, matchNumber)
{
  var match = 0;
  return originalString.replace(searchFor, function(found){
    match++;
    return (match===matchNumber)?replaceWith:found;
  },'g');
}
```